# Access tokens and 2-legged OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, token, 2-legged

I am learning oAuth2 for the first time. I am going to use it to provide authentication for some simple web services using a two-legged approach.

According to what I have read, the flow should go like this: the web service client supplies some kind of credential to the oAuth server (I'm thinking of using JWT). If the credentials are valid, the oAuth server returns an access token. The web service client then supplies the access token when attempting to use the web service end point.

Here is my question, why not just supply the JWT when making a request to the end point? Why is oAuth's flow conceived this way. Why not just supply to JTW to the end point and use that for authentication? What is the advantage of having the extra step of getting an access token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly supply the JWT directly to the web service. The questions is how do you generate it in a way that the service trusts.

> A JWT is and access_token, but not all access_tokens are JWTs.

Your client can issue a JWT, sign it with a key (or a cert) and then send it to the API. The advantage of having a 3rd party (an `Issuer`) is that you can separate authentication from issuing tokens. Clients can authenticate in multiple ways (e.g. usr/pwd, certs, keys, whatever) and then use the JWT to call your API.

The additional abstraction gives you more flexibility and management scalability. For example: if you have 1 consumer of your API, then you are probably ok with a single credential (or JWT, or whatever). If you plan your APIs to be consumed by many clients, then handing that responsibility to a specialized component (e.g. the `the issuer`) makes more sense.

> OAuth BTW, was designed for a specific use case: delegate access to an API to another system on your behalf. You grant access to system-A to access resources on system-B on your behalf with a permission scope.